# is to be doomed

Tags: grammar

I've encountered a sentence like the following. " Our destiny is to be doomed"

What does this mean exactly? And could you give the grammar name for " is to be verb+3" because I couldn't find it on the Internet. I would like to search it on the google as well.

Comment: Syntactically, it's an ambiguous construction (1: *Being doomed is what will happen to **us***, OR 2: *Being doomed is what will happen to **our destiny***). Pragmatically we can probably discard interpretation #2 with your *exact* example, but that's not the case with, say, *My intention is to be kept secret*, where it's unclear whether what I want kept secret is ***myself*** or ***my intention***.

Comment: It's something of a tautology (saying the same thing twice), since my dictionary defines _doom_ as _grim fate or destiny_. The combination 'is to be' is not significant, as you could just as well say "It is our destiny to be doomed" or, more simply "We're doomed!" This was the favourite expression of Private Fraser in the much-loved British sitcom _Dad's Army_.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I understand it now.

Comment: But our hope is to be saved. [Our hope] is [to be saved]. ==> What is our hope? To be saved, that's what it is. ////  It's not the same construction as [The issue] [is to be decided]. =/=> What is the issue? To be decided, that's what it is.

Answer (score 0):

" Our destiny is to be doomed",  is suggesting that, no matter what they [we] do, we will always be doomed [to failure / to repeat past mistakes].

Destiny:

- The events that will necessarily happen to a particular person or thing in the future, or
- The hidden power believed to control future events; fate.

Doomed:

- likely to have an unfortunate and inescapable outcome; ill-fated.

I'm guessing you are studying Romeo & Juliette...?

As for its grammatical name, probably:

- A tautology (saying the same thing twice)